# EntityCommandExecutionException was unhandled see innerException for Details

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ado.net, ado.net-entity-data-model

I am trying to connect my C# application with SQL server compact edition using ADO.NET entity Model.

I think I have been successfully able to generate the model against the database schema.

However when I try to use the entity objects in code I get the

> EntityCommandExecutionException` was unhandled error along with "An
>   error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner
>   exception for details."

Here's the code

```
Database1Entities db = new Database1Entities();
var query = from item in db.People
                    select Name;
foreach (var item in query)
{
    MessageBox.Show("The name of the customer is " + item);
}
```

It says to check inner exception. When I did checked InnerException gave me the error

> "InnerException   {"A parameter is not allowed in this location. Ensure
>   that the '@' sign is in a valid location or that parameters are valid
>   at all in this SQL statement."}   System.Exception
>   {System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException}"

Now I am entirely new to using entity framework for generating objects from database schemas. I would really appreciate some guidance in this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so i made a really nasty mistake.

The problem wasn't with entity framework or connection.

The problem was with my LINQ query.

The correct query is

```
var query = from item in db.People
            select item.Name;
```